How Can I Make a Tube Deform with a Wrapped Rope using Softbody and Cloth Simulation?
I am trying to achieve an effect that I can wrap a rope around a tube to deform it. I got the rope done with a Softbody simulation and some hooks to animate it, but it seems to be that the Cloth simulation is not 'activated': the tube is just static and doesn't react on the rope (or even gravity).
What am I missing here?
See a Cinema4D reference here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y0yWKEKjoaw

